# Carousel-caption is not showing in full width header carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using full width header carousel with captions it is showing images but not captions. trying to find out since morning but unable.

[please check jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yomozon/coxuLkn6/2/)

```
html,
body {
height: 100%;
}

/* You can change the height of the carousel by changing the height in the class below. It is set to 50% by default, but can be any height! */

.carousel {
height: 70%;
 }

.item,
.active,
 .carousel-inner {
height: 100%;
 }

/* Background images are set within the HTML using inline CSS, not here */

.fill {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-position: center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
}

  .carousel .item,
  .carousel .item.active,
 .carousel-caption h2 {
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:60px;
  text-align:center;
 z-index:10;
  }

.carousel-caption .btn-default-outline {
font-family:Century Gothic;
background:none;
border: 4px solid #fff;
color:#fff;
padding: 15px 25px;
 }

.carousel-caption .btn-default-outline:hover {
background-color:#fff;
color:#000000;
}


  footer {
  margin: 50px 0;
}
```

it is not showing carousel caption.

Any one can figure out what is missing or i m doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You might kick yourself when you realize the simplicity of this issue...

this character `”` is wrong for the style attribute in your code and has malformed your HTML.

its starts on this line:

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/archive/0/07/20060606172916%21UCT_Upper_Campus_landscape_view.jpg);”></div>
```

The closing quote is wrong and should be normal quotation mark `"`.

Its a very subtle difference but can cause a lot of issues. It might be a good idea to check all the quotes!

Comment: This is what I found to be the issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your inline-css is blocking the code below that to run. Simply put the inline-css of the three containers to css file.

See the fiddle

## s1 {

```
background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/archive/0/07/20060606172916%21UCT_Upper_Campus_landscape_view.jpg');
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/coxuLkn6/4/

Comment: Yes it is working now. It shows caption now but if now i use local file images then not showing images why is that. In css file i use exactly as you did in jsfiddle but local file images not getting displayed

Comment: You need to mention the complete path of the image in the url. If you don't want to mention the whole path, just keep the files in one folder. Assuming all files are in one folder just do this in css file #s1 { background-image:url('file_name.jpg'); }

Comment: i m using path like this #s1 {
    background-image:url(image/1.jpg);
}
#s2 {
    background-image:url(image/2.jpg);
}
#s3 {
    background-image:url(image/3.jpg);
}

Comment: Are all the files in same folder? #s1 { background-image:url('image1.jpg'); } This is will work.

Comment: i tried {background-image:url(2.jpg);}  and even {background-image:url('2.jpg');} but doesn't shows images from the local file